# Blender 3.2.0 Backwards compatiblity with 2.92 LTS

Tags: compatibility

Is there no backwards compatibility with Blender? When I try and open an model made in 3.x in 2.92 LTS it opens a default scene

Comment: What you are referring to is forward compatibility, opening a file from a newer version in an older version. Backward compatibility is when you are able to open files from older versions in newer versions. Blender provides backward compatibility, but forward compatibility is not guaranteed.

Comment: What worked for me with some not very complex objects was, to select them and copy and paste them into the older version of Blender.